# Why Dattatreya is shown surrounded by 4 dogs and cow?

Tags: scripture, vedas, animals, dattatreya

Simple google search with word "Dattatreya" shows many [images](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=dattatreya&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3zv7B-orXAhULRY8KHZE1AK4Q_AUICigB&biw=1152&bih=561) of lord Dattatreya. but 1 important point to note is in most of those images, lord Dattatreya is shown surrounded by 4 dogs and cow.

[image]

And below,

[image]

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dattatreya) Article on lord Dattatreya, the 4 dogs is a symbolism for the four Vedas and mother earth.

> he is surrounded by four dogs and a cow, which is a symbolism for the
>   four Vedas and mother earth that nourishes all living beings

The citation given in Wikipedia does not point to any scriptural reference for above point and links to [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=7PDr-QF4YmYC&pg=PA95&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Is there a **scriptural reference** which explains why lord Dattatreya is shown surrounded by 4 dogs and cow?

Answer (score 8):

**1. Starting with Cow:**

> CC Madhya 14.223
>
> **ananta kāma-dhenu tāhāṅ phire vane vane dugdha-mātra dena, keha nā
>   māge anya dhane**
>
> “In Vṛndāvana there are cows that fulfill all desires [kāma-dhenus],
>   and their number is unlimited. They graze from forest to forest and
>   deliver only milk. The people want nothing else.

[Refer](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/14/223)

> **Brahmnayam dharma Thathwagnam, Bhakthe keerthi vivardhanam,
>   Bhakthabeeshta pradham vande, Smarthrugaami Sanovathu.**

Translation

> Salutations to him who is holy and master of religion, Whose fame is
>   spread by his devotees, And who fulfills all wishes of his devotees,
>   Who always remember him with faith.
>
> **Jaya Labha yasa kama, Dathur dathasya yasthavam, Bhoga moksha
>   pradaasye maam, Prapathe Sakruthe bhaveth**

Translation

> This prayer addressed to Dathathreya, Gives victory , profit , fame
>   and desire, Happy life and salvation to the one To the one who recites
>   it regularly with faith.

**Conclusion:** kāma-dhenu that fulfill all desires, so does praying Dathathreya, hence cow.

**2. four dogs**

Symbolically, dogs represent loyalty, obedience, devotion, and the Vedas. Bhairava, a fierce form of Shiva, who is worshipped in Tantra, has a dog as his vehicle. [Refer](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/hinduism/essays/sacred-animals-of-hinduism.asp)

[Shvan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shvan), a Sanskrit word meaning a dog, finds repeated references in Vedic and later Hindu mythologies

The expression "Vedic" is derived from the Sanskrit word veda, which means knowledge, wisdom or revelation.

> **Karpoora kanthi dehaya, Brhma moorthy daraya cha, Veda sasthra
>   parignaya, Dathathreya namosthuthe.**
>
> My salutations to Dathathreya, Who has a colour of burning camphor,
>   Who takes up the role of the creator, And who is master of the holy
>   Vedas.

**Conclusion:** Dathathreya a god in the form of a combination of the great trinity consisting of Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva, Brahma created Vedas, Dathathreya master of all 4 vedas & dog symbolic of Vedas, hence four dogs.

Refer [1](http://www.celextel.org/stotras/vishnu/dattakshamapanastotram.html) and [2](https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/guru-tattvam-a-dattatreya-jayanthi-special)

Comment: your post does makes a good case of associating properties of cow and dog to the qualities associated with Lord Dattatreya. However, i am looking for more explicit mention of cow and dog and their connection or may be a incidence from Hindu scriptures which has some correlation of cow and dog with Lord Dattatreya